# Why is the set() reversing the list?

Tags: python, list

When I run the set() function in python to convert from a list to set and to remove duplicates, the set function is reversing the order of my list.

```
x = ['2','6']
y = list(set(x))
print('x is',str(x),'y is',str(y))
```

Comment: Well sets are unordered, so `['6', '2']` is entirely possible.

Comment: A set is not guaranteeing you order it is guaranteeing you uniqueness of its elements.

Comment: Sets are unordered, and the iteration order isn't guaranteed to be related to the insertion order used to create the set.

Comment: `[i for i in set(x)]` returns `['6', '2']` .So, the iteration order isn't guaranteed to be related to the iteration order used to create the set.

Answer (score 2):

When you build the set, each element from the list is added in the order that the `list_iterator` (produced by `iter(x)`) yields them.

A set, though, is unordered, and the insertion order is neither remembered nor used to construct the iteration order of the set itself.

As a result, `list(set(x))` produces a list whose order is unrelated to the order of `x` in any meaningful fashion.

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, `set` doesn't preserve order. A good alternative is `OrderedDict`, which guarantees unique keys and preserves order.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

x = ['1','1','2','3','4','5','5','5','6','7','8','9','9']
y = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(x))

print("x is", x)
print("y is", y)

# x is ['1', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '5', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '9']
# y is ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
```

Comment: As of Python 3.6 dicts are **insertion** ordered so `dict.fromkeys(x)` will be fine also

Comment: Good point about `dict`, although Python 3.6 introduced this just in the CPython implementation. In 3.7 preserving insert order became a language feature and should be available for all implementations.